# Convert type 'str' to numerator/ denominator

Tags: python, string, list

I'm having some trouble converting type 'str' to numbers. I use a separate text-file containing the following numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and then I import these numbers into python and save them as a list.  However, by doing this, I get a list of strings as follows: `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`. I want to convert this list of strings so the list represents numbers, i.e. the output should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

My code is:

```
def imported_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        contents = f.read().splitlines() 
    print(contents)
imported_numbers('sample.txt')
```

Is there a specific command to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: What does numerator/denominator have to do with this?

Comment: imported_numbers does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map):

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

new_l = list(map(int, l))  # or just map(int, l) in Python 2
```

will return

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This can throw an error if there are strings that cannot be converted to numbers though:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'lkj']

list(map(int, l))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lkj'

So make sure your input is valid and/or wrap it into a `try/except`.

Answer (score 3):

IMO it's more pythonic to say

```
str_list = ['1', '2', '3']
new_list = [int(n) for n in str_list]
```

If you're not sure all of the strings will be valid numbers, you need to add appropriate error handling.