# How can I debug this error 'float' object is not iterable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compute the mean values of the numbers in a list of lists, I'm supposed to skip over the first observation (i.e position 0) because they are the names of countries, I only need to calculate the mean of every column after `[0]`. 
However, my code keeps saying:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

If anyone could have a look and offer some help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

p.s I can't use `numpy` or `pandas`.

```
test_list = [['name1', 6.039330006, 0, 0.00, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, None], ['name2', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.00001]]
```

```py
def my_mean(file): 

# This function calculates the mean value of each column in the file

    mean_list = [ ]
    for row in range(0,len(file)): 
        for column in range(1,len(file[0])):
            if file[row][column] != None:
               mean_value = stat.mean(file[row][column])
               # mean_value = sum(file[row][column])/ len(1,file[row][column])
        mean_list.append(mean_value)
    print("The mean values are {0}".format(mean_list))
```

With a similar code I was able to get:

The minimum values are `[-0.186299905, 0.246900991]` for the two columns in the `test_list`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us the traceback, please, and also how you are invoking your function. Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

For each column of your data, we build a list of the values it contains, filtering out the `None` ones, and pass it to `mean`:

```
import statistics

def my_mean(file): 
    # This function calculates the mean value of each column in the file
    mean_list = [ ]
    for column in range(1,len(file[0])):
        column_values = (row[column] for row in file)
        mean_list.append(statistics.mean(val for val in column_values if val is not None))

    return mean_list          


test_list = [['name1', 6.039330006, 0, 0.00, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, None], ['name2', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.00001]]  
print(my_mean(test_list))

# [5.163533211000001, 4.517355442, 0.348962456, 66.33219528500001, 0.722831607, -0.159233041, 1e-05]
```

You could also use `zip` to build the list of columns, then calculate the means in a list comprehension:

```
import statistics

def my_mean(file): 
    columns = list(zip(*file))[1:]
    mean_list = [statistics.mean(val for val in column if val is not None) for column in columns]
    return mean_list          


test_list = [['name1', 6.039330006, 0, 0.00, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, None], ['name2', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.00001]]  
print(my_mean(test_list))

# [5.163533211000001, 4.517355442, 0.348962456, 66.33219528500001, 0.722831607, -0.159233041, 1e-05]
```

Comment: @YasinYousif That would exclude the values equal to 0, which would change the mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for the test list but would you know why it would produce this error for a list that is a variable within a function? TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' ? but it's a list not a string?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille , that's right,.. I guess that I hate using formulas like `None==None` , I feel it is always may change with different versions, .. (*in javascript that's used to cause trouble*). so, to the extent of my limited knowledge, it's safer not to use them!

Comment: @Helena: This error must happen in some other part of your code, there's no comparison involved anywhere here. If you don't manage to solve it, you can ask another question!

Comment: @YasinYousif Using `None` is really safe in Python. As stated in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types, "This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name None. It is used to signify the absence of a value in many situations, e.g., it is returned from functions that don’t explicitly return anything.". The traditional way to test if a value is `None` is `if value is None:`, thus testing if both are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your approach, I would do it like this:

```
def my_mean(file): 
mean_list = []
for row in range(len(file)): 
    temp_column = []
    for column in range(len(file[row])):
        if isinstance(file[row][column], (int, float)):
            temp_column.append(file[row][column])

    mean_value = sum(temp_column) / len(temp_column)
    mean_list.append(mean_value)

print("The mean values are {0}".format(mean_list))
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a reason why it wouldn't iterate through the floated values?

Comment: Well yes, in your code you had `stat.mean(file[row][column])` which is a float, a single number. In order to calculate mean you need to `sum()` and divide by `len()` and in order to get an answer from `len()` you need to iterate through the items, but when you pass a single object you cannot iterate over it.

Comment: OK so this might be related to the ```TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator``` error that I get when I try to pass a list/variable defined in a function?

Comment: regarding this you might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696397/convert-type-str-to-numerator-denominator

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
test_list = [['name1', 6.039330006, 0, 0.00, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, None],
             ['name2', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.00001]]
```

```
def mean(x):
    i=r=0.0
    for c in x:
        if c or c==0: 
            r+=c;i+=1
    return r/i

numbers_list = [row[1:] for row in test_list]

print('Result')
print([mean(x) for x in zip(*numbers_list)])
```

it gives:

**Result**

[5.163533211000001, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 66.33219528500001, 0.722831607, -0.159233041, 1e-05]

Comment: `mean([0, 2])` returns `2.0`, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille , noted